# dependencyClasspath error on Play! 2.2 as play.db.ebean cannot be found

Tags: java, playframework

I am running Play! 2.2 and want my models to extend play.db.ebean. I have one model called Event which extends play.db.ebean.Model. I get the following compilation errors when I try to generate Eclipse files (from the play command line) because the application cannot find the play.db.ebean package:

```
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[info] Compiling 6 Scala sources and 7 Java sources to C:\Users\nickc\gatherme\target\scala-2.10\classes... error: cannot find symbol
[error] public abstract class Event_ extends play.db.ebean.Model_ {
[error]   symbol:   class Model_
[error]   location: package play.db.ebean
[error] 1 error
[error] Could not create Eclipse project files:
[error] Error evaluating task 'dependencyClasspath': error
```

I have the following in my build.sbt file:

```
import play.Project._

name := "forms"

version := "1.0"

val appDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaEbean,
  jdbc
) 

playJavaSettings
```

This is as suggested [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Build) and in the Zentasks sample project. I am guessing that my build.sbt file must be wrong? Or not getting picked up?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Nick

Comment: Do you really have new lines in your `appDependencies` or is it just pasted like this? You shouldn't have new lines inside an expression in `build.sbt` (although I'm not sure this is your problem).

Comment: @Ipiepiora No, I don't have new lines in my `appDependencies` but couldn't get the formatting to work above.